# Does '&' mean something special in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a View in microsoft sql server management studio that uses the code

`WHEN (CHARINDEX('&', page_url) > 0)`

in a case statement, does the & mean something special?

Even in strings with a url that does not contain '&' it seems to be greater than 0...?

Comment: Do you really ask what you want answered? @cHao is right to what you are asking atm.

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of such a string where the result is unexpected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character '&' means nothing special, when used within a string -- it's just an ampersand.  <strike>No SQL engine that i know of treats it specially.</strike>  (OK, apparently Oracle does something wacky with it.  But SQL server definitely doesn't, and neither does any other DBMS i've worked with.)

Comment: I will take your word for it, there may be some other logic issues creating the issue I am looking for that I have not presented in this question...  I will test and get back to this if I find otherwise... thanks!

Comment: @cHao It's been a while but I think it denotes a substitution variable

Comment: @Phil: Thanks for bringing that up.   Updated.  :)

Comment: @phil what does it mean in Oracle / SQL*Plus ?

Comment: @tylercomp As you're using SQL Server it doesn't apply to your problem but for an answer, see 3 comments up

Answer (score 1):

No, it should just return the index.  Run this example to see:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('&', 'test&test')
```

This returns 5 as you would expect.  Can you post what string it's not returning the expected results for?

Answer (score 0):

It has no special meaning. Do a test yourself:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('&', 'http://blah.com/page.html?q=one&w=another')
```

Should return 32

```
SELECT CHARINDEX('&', 'http://blah.com/page.html?q=one')
```

Should return 0

The problem may lie elsewhere in your CASE statement.

Comment: Is this to mean that Strings are 1 indexed instead of 0 indexed in this case?